# How to prevent the URL to append with the current URL in kendo mobile UI application with asp.net MVC`

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, kendo-ui

I have created a mobile application using kendo Mobile UI's trial version in asp.net MVC3.
Here I am facing a problem that whenever I click on any anchor tag/button then its url get appended with the current page's url.
eg: **www.testkendoui.com/CurrentPage_Controller/CurrentPage_Action#/www.testkendoui.com/NextPage_Controller/NextPage_Action**

And this causes the next page not to work, and it works after refreshing the next page.

I have tried with :
1.) data-ajax="false" on all anchor tags and forms.
2.) adding "http://" with the main URL 
but that all does not working.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.. :)

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on any links / buttons that you want to do a full postback you need to set the data-rel attribute to external.

IE:

```
<a href="/logoff" data-ajax="false" rel="external" data-rel="external" data-role="button" data-align="right" >Log Off</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Where kendoui requires a url use the following (assuming you are using Razor):

```
$('someitem').kendoXYZ({
     url: "@Url.Action("MVC Action", "MVC Controller")"
}
```

Note the quotes around the @Url.Action are important.

Hope this helps!